# PC pins Python to taskbar instead of the Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, taskbar

So, I installed Anaconda to get access to Spyder, Jupyter, etc.. I then opened Anaconda Navigator and pinned it to my taskbar. I come back a day later, click on the pinned item just for it to open the literal Python shell, not the Anaconda Navigator. Help? Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Pin Anaconda Navigator from the Start Menu instead of pinning the running application. This way it should preserve the icon and correct launcher script arguments.

Open the Start Menu, find Anaconda Navigator, right click and select "Pin to taskbar"

[image: Pin anaconda from start menu]

It won't work if you try to pin the running application because the shortcut will be missing the needed arguments (`C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py`).